# How to verify SSRS Reporting Services installation

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

**ETA2:** Solved, see answer below.

**ETA:** The below is specific to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. Since then I've uninstalled express and installed SQL Server 2008 R2 enterprise edition. The problem still exists, the only difference is that the virtual server directory is now called **ReportServer**, not **ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS2**.

---

I've installed SSRS for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express in Native Mode. I left everything at default values during the installation.

If I open up the 'Reporting Services Configuration Manager' and click 'Web Service URL', I see:

Virtual Directory: ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS2
IP Address: All Assigned (Recommended)
TCP Port: 80
SSL Certificate: (Not Selected)
SSL Port: ...

URLs: `http://225-PC:80/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS2`

This url doesn't work (HTTP 404).
I've verified that the reporting service is running.

Is there some other operation I have to perform before the above url works?

Comment: Please specify "doesn't work": how are you testing it, and what kind of error/response do you get?

Comment: I've amended the question - HTTP 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to open up port 80 on the firewall.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934283.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I would think you'd want to continue through and set up the database connection as well. Then things should work.  If it's not, there could be a network or config issues.

Comment: I have verified that the database has been set up - this was done for me automatically.